# D3 data do not rescale properly after pan or zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working with D3 v4 and JS. I have a scatter plot with a predefined set of data loaded along with axes with the ability to pan and zoom. I need to be able to then dynamically add points and eventually output them in data space not pixel space. I am using the "rescaleX" and "rescaleY" methods of the zoom object. They work fine for rescaling the axes but, when I try to add new points, the location of the plotted point does correspond to the mouse location. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var data = [{x:17,y:3},
        {x:20,y:16},
        {x:2,y:13},
        {x:19,y:10},
        {x:13,y:15},
        {x:2,y:2},
        {x:5,y:8},
        {x:11,y:19},
        {x:20,y:12},
        {x:10,y:20}];

    var width = 600;
    var height = 600;
    var padding = 50;
    var newXscale, newYscale;

    var dataScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,21])
        .range([0, width]);

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width+2*padding)
        .attr('height', height+2*padding)
        .on('click', clicked);

    var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
        .scale(dataScale);

    var gX = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate(50,50)')
        .call(xAxis);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(dataScale);

    var gY = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate(50,50)')
        .call(yAxis);

    var canvas = svg.append('g')

    var points = canvas.append('g');
    points.selectAll('circle').data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {return dataScale(d.x)+padding})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {return dataScale(d.y)+padding})
        .attr('r', 5);

    var zoom
    var zoomOn = false;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key=='z') {
            if (zoomOn) {
                d3.select('#zoomBox').remove();
                zoomOn = false;
            } else {
                zoom = d3.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
                    .on('zoom', zoomed);

                svg.append("rect")
                    .attr('cursor','move')
                    .attr("width", width+padding*2)
                    .attr("height", height+padding*2)
                    .attr('id','zoomBox')
                    .style("fill", "none")
                    .style("pointer-events", "all")
                    .call(zoom);
                zoomOn = true;
            }

        }
    });

    function zoomed() {
        canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        newXscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(dataScale);
        newYscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(dataScale);
        gX.call(xAxis.scale(newXscale));
        gY.call(yAxis.scale(newYscale));
    }

    function clicked() {
        var coords = d3.mouse(this);
        points.append('circle')
            .attr('cx',coords[0])
            .attr('cy',coords[1])
            .attr('r',5);
        var x = newXscale.invert(coords[0]-padding);
        var y = newYscale.invert(coords[1]-padding);
        console.log(x+' '+y);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to store the zoom level:

```
newZscale = d3.event.transform.k;
```

And, in your `clicked` function, use the `dateScale` to plot the new circles, dividing the padding by the zoom level:

```
function clicked() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    if (newXscale && newYscale) {
        var x = newXscale.invert(coords[0] - padding);
        var y = newYscale.invert(coords[1] - padding);
    };
    console.log(newZscale);
    points.append('circle')
        .attr('cx', (!x) ? coords[0] : dataScale(x) + (padding / newZscale))
        .attr('cy', (!y) ? coords[1] : dataScale(y) + (padding / newZscale))
        .attr('r', 5);
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
    x: 17,
    y: 3
}, {
    x: 20,
    y: 16
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 13
}, {
    x: 19,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 13,
    y: 15
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 2
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 11,
    y: 19
}, {
    x: 20,
    y: 12
}, {
    x: 10,
    y: 20
}];

var width = 600;
var height = 600;
var padding = 50;
var newXscale, newYscale, newZscale;

var dataScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 21])
    .range([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + 2 * padding)
    .attr('height', height + 2 * padding)
    .on('click', clicked);

var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(dataScale);

var gX = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)')
    .call(xAxis);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(dataScale);

var gY = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)')
    .call(yAxis);

var canvas = svg.append('g')

var points = canvas.append('g');
points.selectAll('circle').data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return dataScale(d.x) + padding
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return dataScale(d.y) + padding
    })
    .attr('r', 5);

var zoom
var zoomOn = false;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key == 'z') {
        if (zoomOn) {
            d3.select('#zoomBox').remove();
            zoomOn = false;
        } else {
            zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
                .on('zoom', zoomed);



            svg.append("rect")
                .attr('cursor', 'move')
                .attr("width", width + padding * 2)
                .attr("height", height + padding * 2)
                .attr('id', 'zoomBox')
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("pointer-events", "all")
                .call(zoom);
            zoomOn = true;
        }

    }
});

function zoomed() {
    canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    newXscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(dataScale);
    newYscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(dataScale);
    newZscale = d3.event.transform.k;
    gX.call(xAxis.scale(newXscale));
    gY.call(yAxis.scale(newYscale));
}

function clicked() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    if (newXscale && newYscale) {
        var x = newXscale.invert(coords[0] - padding);
        var y = newYscale.invert(coords[1] - padding);
    };
    points.append('circle')
        .attr('cx', (!x) ? coords[0] : dataScale(x) + (padding / newZscale))
        .attr('cy', (!y) ? coords[1] : dataScale(y) + (padding / newZscale))
        .attr('r', 5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I'm still a bit confused, however. After zooming, shouldn't the domain of my scaling change? Is there some transform going on in the background? It seems like I should be using the newXscale and newYscale objects for rendering new points after zooming.

Comment: After working with this a little more I've discovered a problem with the solution. This works fine as long as you don't try zooming again. However, if you zoom, add points, and then zoom again, the scale suddenly jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem lied in the fact that I was removing the zoom box when toggling the zoom. I switched the event listener to just hide the box and unbind the pointer-events. Here is the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var data = [{x:17,y:3},
        {x:20,y:16},
        {x:2,y:13},
        {x:19,y:10},
        {x:13,y:15},
        {x:2,y:2},
        {x:5,y:8},
        {x:11,y:19},
        {x:20,y:12},
        {x:10,y:20}];

    var width = 600;
    var height = 600;
    var padding = 50;
    var newXscale, newYscale;
    var zoomOn = false;

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,21])
        .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,21])
        .range([0, width]);

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width+2*padding)
        .attr('height', height+2*padding)
        .on('click', clicked)
        .attr('cursor','crosshair');

    var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
        .scale(xScale);

    var gX = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate(50,50)')
        .call(xAxis);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScale);

    var gY = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate(50,50)')
        .call(yAxis);

    var canvas = svg.append('g')

    var points = canvas.append('g');
    points.selectAll('circle').data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.x)+padding})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {return yScale(d.y)+padding})
        .attr('r', 5);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
        .on('zoom', zoomed);

    var zoombox = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width+padding*2)
        .attr("height", height+padding*2)
        .attr('id','zoomBox')
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .style('visibility','off')
        .call(zoom);

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key=='z') {
            if (zoomOn) {
                d3.select('#zoomBox')
                    .attr('cursor','auto')
                    .style('pointer-events','none')
                    .style('visibility','off');
                zoomOn = false;
            } else {
                d3.select('#zoomBox')
                    .attr('cursor','move')
                    .style('pointer-events','all')
                    .style('visibilty','on')
                zoomOn = true;
            }

        }
    });

    function zoomed() {
        canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        newXscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
        newYscale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);
        gX.call(xAxis.scale(newXscale));
        gY.call(yAxis.scale(newYscale));
        newZscale = d3.event.transform.k;

    }

    function clicked() {
        var coords = d3.mouse(this);
        if (newXscale && newYscale) {
            var x = newXscale.invert(coords[0] - padding);
            var y = newYscale.invert(coords[1] - padding);
        };
        console.log(newZscale);
        points.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', (!x) ? coords[0] : xScale(x) + (padding / newZscale))
            .attr('cy', (!y) ? coords[1] : yScale(y) + (padding / newZscale))
            .attr('r', 5);
        console.log(x + ' ' + y);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, this didn't entirely fix things either. Now the data are shifting slightly upon zooming. I'm at a complete loss now. I think it's just the rendering that is shifted because mouse clicks still give accurate coordinates.